# RegEx or PowerShell to remove repeat characters in sequence

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

Writing a script to convert a Windows host file into a CSV.  Used RegEx to get to this stage:

```
1.1.1.1,,server1,,,
2.2.2.2,,server2
3.3.3.3,,server3
4.5.6.7,,server4,,server5,,server6,,server7,,
8.8.8.8,,server8
9.9.9.9,server9
```

I need some RegEx that can remove the duplicate commas (in sequence) so it would look like this:

```
1.1.1.1,server1,
2.2.2.2,server2
3.3.3.3,server3
4.5.6.7,server4,server5,server6,server7,
8.8.8.8,server8
9.9.9.9,server9
```

Will also need to remove the comma at the end of each line (if there is one) but think this will be simpler to do.

Comment: Replace `,+` with `,` ?

Comment: -replace ',+', ','                 works thank you

Answer (score 3):

The regex for your first task of removing duplicate commas was already provided in the comments above, but if you also want to remove trailing commas at the end of the line, you can use this to solve both problems at once:

```
(?m),(?=,|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?m)  # turn on multiline mode ($ matches end-of-line, not just end-of-string)
,     # Match a comma
(?=   # only if followed by
 ,    # another comma
|     # or
 $    # the end of the string.
)     # End of lookahead assertion
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4BhpRP/1).

Comment: `(?=,|$)` is better explained as a [Positive Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thanks, was going to use a loop and if eol = , but will give this a try

Comment: Just confirmed this works perfectly, thanks again